# Joomla create content plugin to add fields to article (com_content)

Tags: joomla-3.x, plugin, com-content

Am a beginner to joomla development ,id like to add extra fields to the article (`com_content`)component. I have read this article 
https://docs.joomla.org/Adding_custom_fields_to_the_article_component
However it does not fully answer my question on when / how to add the extra fields to the table `_content` table , and when to add the inserted data .Any help is greatly appreciated .

Comment: If I were you I would have a look at http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/aixeena-cck

Answer (score 2):

The easiest approach is to simply add the fields as additional properties of the attribs, so you don't need to handle database changes; the additional properties will be stored as a string representing a json object.

As you can see in the document you linked, `<fields name="attribs">` is the container of all custom properties in the manifest file (the .xml), and it will automatically handle the persistance for you.

Positive connsiderations:

- you only create and inject the manifest, the framework handles the rest;
- there is no need for database changes

Negative considerations:

- Search requires you to handle the json structure of the attribs field
- Search will be incredibly slower unless you add json support to your database, and implement the proper indexes, which will put you in a non-default situation. This only applies with 1000+ articles or very slow hosting.